# Reverse scrollview height controlled by stack view in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

**My Goal**

To make a reverse scroll view that changes height with the height of the vertical stack (the contents of which will be controlled programatically)

**What I have tried**

Setting the stack view, Scroll view and content view the same heights. I am not sure how to change the simulated size of the view controller with it

Note: I am using Storyboard not swift UI, I have researched this and all I can find are tutorials for how to do this in SwiftUI

I wanted it to be controlled by the height of the stack view, so it does not scroll when there isn't anything to scroll to, if this is wrong please correct me and give me some guidance

The ViewController now:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is a "reverse" stack view? What is a "reverse" scroll view?

Comment: If the only thing directly inside the scroll view is the stack view, what is the content view for? The stack view should _be_ the content view. The stack view, if pinned to the scroll view's content guide, will then size the content "from the inside out", giving exactly the effect you seem to be after.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant reverse scroll view- I didn't mean stack view, and the videos I watched described a reverse scroll view that as being where the the things you want to view are at the bottom and you scroll up for the older stuff (I know that is a terrible explanation but I am trying to mean like how iMessage is set out)

Comment: Well I don't see how that "reverse" is germane to the problem. See my previous comment.

Comment: I have removed the content view, but how do I make the actual page get longer as more things are added into the stack view, because the tutorial I learnt from gave a fixed simulated size for the view controller in the measure inspector? And thank you for helping me I am quite new to this

Comment: I do not know what "the actual page" is. I'm just talking about how to make a scroll view scrollable or not depending on what its contents are.

Comment: The tutorial I used must have been incorrect then because I am now seeing what you mean and I do need to do what you are saying. So I can ignore the 'reverse' part and just focus on how to make the scroll view scrollable or not depending on what its contents are. So how would I go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I had a similar issue recently.
My solution was:

1. Fully constrain the UIScrollview within the superview
2. Place a UIView inside the UIScrollView. Align the UIView's leading and trailing constraints to the UIScrollView's content layout guide AND frame layout guide ( =0, or whatever margin you need).  Align the UIView's top and bottom constraints to the UIScrollView's content layout guide ( =0 ).  Constrain the UIView's height to be equal to the height of the UIScrollView's frame layout guide with a priority of 500 (make sure the multiplier is 1 as Autolayout might set it to something else).  These constraints should be added by control dragging from the UIView to the UIScrollView's layout guides within the document outline (I had problems if I didn't add them this way).  This fixes the widths, but if the UIView's height needs to expand then the equal height constraint can break allowing it to grow outside the UIScrollView's frame, triggering scrolling.
3. Place your UIStackView inside the UIView.  Align the UIStackView leading and trailing constraints to the superview (the UIView), or use a horizontally centred within superview constraint.  Constrain the UIStackView to be vertically centred within the superview (again, the UIView). Align the bottom constraint of the UIStackView to be >=0 relative to the superview (UIView). Thus, when the UIStackView is smaller than the UIView (and UIScrollView) it remains centred and doesn't scroll.  As soon as the UIStackView (and UIView) exceeds the size of the UIScrollView, the >=0 constraint between UIStackView and UIView bottom takes precedence over the equal height constraint between the UIView and UIScrollView frame layout guide, forcing scrolling.

In step 3, I think you might be better served by aligning the top of the UIStackView to the top of the UIView, rather than having the UIStackView vertically centred.  The bottom constraint should still be >=0. I didn't try this myself but it should still work.

If you need the UIScrollView itself to increase in size, then pin its top and bottom within the superview to the minimum size you want it to be, with a low priority such as 250, then add >= constraints to fix the outer limit of where you want it to be. For example, Constrain the bottom of the UIScrollView to be =100 from the bottom safe area guide with a priority of 250, then constrain it to also be >= 25 from the bottom safe area with the default priority of 1000.  In this case the first constraint to break should be the bottom of the UIScrollView which will allow the UIScrollView to grow until it hits the bottom >=25 constraint, at which point the UIView to UIScrollView_frame_layout_guide equal height constraint will break triggering scrolling.

I hope that makes sense (and that I haven't missed anything)!

PS I also ran into a problem with the UIStackView contents (programatically defined in my case) resizing in odd ways which seemed to be fixed by changing content mode from "Scale to Fill" to "Redraw".  I set distribution to "Fill Equally" or "Fill Proportionally" depending on the look I wanted (I had two such views).